# error C2664: 'wcscmp' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CHAR [260]' to 'const wchar_t *'

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have this code which working on vs2019

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <windows.h>
PROCESSENTRY32 pe32 = { 0 };
HANDLE    hSnap;
int       iDone;
int       iTime = 60;
bool      bProcessFound;
using namespace std;
int x = 1;
int i = 0;

int main() {
    system("cmd /C \"\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\tool.exe\"\"");
    /*WinExec("cmd /C \"\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\tool.exe\"\"", SW_HIDE);*/
    Sleep(1000);
    /*for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {

        Sleep(1000);
        cout << i << "\n";
        x++;
        if (i == 10) i = 0;
    }*/

    while (true)    // go forever
    {
        hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
        pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
        Process32First(hSnap, &pe32);     // Can throw away, never an actual app

        bProcessFound = false;   //init values
        iDone = 1;

        while (iDone)    // go until out of Processes
        {
            iDone = Process32Next(hSnap, &pe32);
            if (wcscmp(pe32.szExeFile, CString("tool.exe")) == 0)    // Did we find our process?
            {
                bProcessFound = true;
                iDone = 0;
                cout << "process found" << "\n";
            }
        }

        if (!bProcessFound)    // if we didn't find it running...
        {
            cout << "process not found" << "\n";
        }
        Sleep(iTime * 500);    // delay x amount of seconds.
    }

    
}
```

but when i put it and compiled with an older version of vs (2003 version), i got this error

error C2664: 'wcscmp' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CHAR [260]' to 'const wchar_t *' Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

what should i do?

Comment: You need to add `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` in your preprocessor defines, so things like `PROCESSENTRY32` resolve to `PROCESSENTRY32W`

Comment: I did what you advise sir but still no luck.

Comment: "I did what you advise" Works for me, you are doing something wrong, please post a [mcve].

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. if it is work for you then good for you. And for you're information, the posted program above was attached on a very large system.

Comment: If it works for me but not for you, it means I am doing something right and you are doing it wrong. If you want to know what you are doing wrong, you need to show what you are doing first. "I did what you advise" is not an adequate description of what you have done.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I give the error and it was upon compilation and what else do i need to post? If you want to help, you mind to answer like this"Just post the whole system so i can see what's wrong with it".

Comment: Please read on how to create a [mcve]. We don't need your entire system. Just the part that produces the error. It is your responsibility to extract and show just that part.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I already posted it, i don't know if you understand sorry if it is hard for you to understand it. The moment that code above was being complied in v2019, it runs and has no errors. But when we tried to to 2003, the code has an error and i wrote it already error C2664: 'wcscmp' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CHAR [260]' to 'const wchar_t *' Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast. What else do i need to post? that code will help us a lot

Comment: The program you have posted compiles when `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` are defined, and does not compile when `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` are not defined. Therefore, the statement "I did what you advise" does not reflect reality. A [mcve] should also include your build command or whatever you use to compile your program. Perhaps you need advise on how to compile a big project with unicode settings, in which case you need to ask just this question.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I defined it as he said. i defined it like this #define UNICODE as google answer it like that. Is that wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and modify the program such that it is **exactloy** what you are compiling. Don't say "I added this and that" in comments.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. be considerate for not all people here are english people. This language is not my native language and that's how i wrote and understand my own answer.

Comment: Not sure what English has to do with it. You are saying you have inserted `#define UNICODE` but I don't see it in the code, so I have no way to know if you have done it correctly.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. i added it  below  #include <windows.h> at the code above. tenfour just told me to define it and so i did. i also replaced PROCESSENTRY32  to PROCESSENTRY32W, but it has the same error as above.

Comment: @itTech what you don't understand is that this error is very well-known and it's exactly fixed by what I suggested. Do not dismiss it, it is precisely the correct answer. If it's "not working for you", you need to figure out what you did wrong. Maybe you put these `#defines` below `#include <windows.h>` for example. Troubleshoot. Or if you're now getting a different error message, then update the question. There's nothing more to say about your question.

Comment: @tenfour it has the same error as above. I think i need to test the other codes.

Comment: "i added it below #include <windows.h>" well that's exactly the problem. You need to add it before any include directives, or better yet set up your build environment so that it is added to compiler flags instead.

Answer (score -1):

If the strings are null-terminated (which your strings looks to be), you can simply pass a pointer to the first letter. Should work with the 2003 compiler just fine.

Here is a copy-paste example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    wstring str1 = L"We are equal!";
    wstring str2 = L"We are equal!";
    wstring str3 = L"I'm special!";

    bool TWO_FIRST_EQUAL      = wcscmp(&str1[0], &str2[0]) == 0;
    bool LAST_AND_FIRST_EQUAL = wcscmp(&str1[0], &str3[0]) == 0;
    //                                 ^    ^^^  ^    ^^^

    wcout << L"Are the first two strings equal?: "    << (TWO_FIRST_EQUAL      ? L"YES" : L"NO") << endl << endl;
    wcout << L"Is the last one equal to the first?: " << (LAST_AND_FIRST_EQUAL ? L"YES" : L"NO") << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: To compare two `wstring` variables you just do `str1 == str2`.  No need to call C functions with pointers.